# all elements in domain[n] are witnessed in Python

Tags: python

I need to apply the coupon collector problem and I need to generate random numbers between 1 to n so that all elements in domain [n] are witnessed.

Here is part of my code.. any help please?

```
import random


DOMAIN_LOW = 0
DOMAIN_HIGH = 100


       current = random.randrange(DOMAIN_LOW, DOMAIN_HIGH)
```

Comment: So you want to check each integer between 0 and 100 once each?

Comment: yes. when generating the random numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what you meant, you want to generate random numbers until it has generated all numbers from domain_low to domain_high.

Here's what you're looking for

```
import random

DOMAIN_LOW = 0
DOMAIN_HIGH = 100

elements = list()
numbers_generated = 0

while True:
    numbers_generated += 1
    random_num = random.randint(DOMAIN_LOW, DOMAIN_HIGH)

    if random_num not in elements:
        elements.append(random_num)

    if len(elements) == DOMAIN_HIGH - DOMAIN_LOW:
        break
print(elements)
print(numbers_generated)
```

Comment: I want to generate random numbers until it has generated all numbers from domain_low to domain_high ( 0 to 100 ), taken in consideration it might has a collision ( repetition of some numbers), but I want to make sure they all the numbers from 0 to 100 have been generated, and probably the total of number generated will be more than 100 because of the collision

Answer (score 0):

You need `shuffle` function from `random` module that shuffle a list :

```
>>> from random import shuffle
>>> DOMAIN_LOW = 0
>>> DOMAIN_HIGH = 100
>>> x=range(DOMAIN_LOW, DOMAIN_HIGH)
>>> shuffle(x)
>>> x
[59, 57, 70, 28, 79, 52, 91, 56, 55, 66, 19, 50, 44, 30, 29, 90, 80, 2, 77, 8, 13, 82, 74, 39, 11, 43, 61, 65, 72, 10, 88, 21, 89, 1, 6, 41, 12, 9, 96, 0, 42, 47, 64, 78, 73, 58, 20, 34, 53, 92, 85, 83, 18, 62, 98, 33, 54, 27, 45, 16, 48, 4, 5, 36, 37, 15, 99, 38, 14, 3, 31, 40, 63, 68, 86, 95, 97, 87, 81, 94, 71, 26, 67, 60, 69, 25, 84, 7, 23, 76, 49, 17, 32, 35, 24, 93, 75, 46, 22, 51]
```

so then you can use a loop to choose your element that is between 1 - 100 .

Comment: I don't think this will work cause I need to know how many trials it took until all the elements has been witnessed.

Comment: @Lelo sorry i couldn't get your mean !!! can you show an example or more explain ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @echorange:

```
elements = list()
numbers_generated = 0

while True:
    numbers_generated += 1
    random_num = random.randint(DOMAIN_LOW, DOMAIN_HIGH)

    if random_num not in elements:
        elements.append(random_num)

    if len(elements) == DOMAIN_HIGH - DOMAIN_LOW:
        break
```

is OK but needs a little bit of improvement

Firstly your problem statement is a little vague about your domain: does it include `DOMAIN_HIGH` or not?  This is a common source of "off by one" errors.  In your example you use `randrange` thereby hinting that you do not include the right hand end, which is typical for Python.  Unfortunately the `randint` function used by @echorange untypically does include the right hand end and that makes the code out by one. Either it needs to switch to `randrange` or change the test to be

```
if len(elements) == DOMAIN_HIGH - DOMAIN_LOW + 1:
```

Having got that out of the way, the code works.  But this bit is not efficient at all in Python - testing membership in a list takes time proportional to the length of the list, so for larger domains this will be annoying slow.

```
if random_num not in elements:
    elements.append(random_num)
```

Python provides an easy fix to this: use a set instead of a list.  Finally a simple optimisation is to move constant calculations out of the loop: compute the size of the domain up front:

```
DOMAIN_LOW = 0
DOMAIN_HIGH = 100
DOMAIN_SIZE = DOMAIN_HIGH - DOMAIN_LOW

elements = set()
numbers_generated = 0

while len(elements) < DOMAIN_SIZE:
    numbers_generated += 1
    random_num = random.randrange(DOMAIN_LOW, DOMAIN_HIGH)
    elements.add(random_num)

print(numbers_generated)
```

This is significantly faster as the size of the domain gets larger.  Performance is not necessarily a good reason to re-write, but for simulations like this it is often very important.  Furthermore, the revised version is not less readable.

However, using a set here is overkill - in Python it is efficient but in a static language an even more efficient solution could use a simple array type, since your domain is a contiguous range of integers.  We can demonstrate that in Python:

```
DOMAIN_LOW = 0
DOMAIN_HIGH = 100
DOMAIN_SIZE = DOMAIN_HIGH - DOMAIN_LOW

elements = [True] * DOMAIN_SIZE
numbers_generated = 0
numbers_used = 0

while numbers_used  < DOMAIN_SIZE:
    numbers_generated += 1
    random_num = random.randrange(0, DOMAIN_SIZE)

    if elements[random_num]:
        elements[random_num] = False
        numbers_used += 1

print(numbers_generated)
```

In Python this is not really any faster, but in a language like C it would be considerably so.

A quick test on a version using a domain of size 10000 gives timings of 11.8s, 0.3s, and 0.24s for the original, set, and list versions respectively.

Comment: I want to generate random numbers until it has generated all numbers from domain_low to domain_high ( 0 to 100 ), taken in consideration it might has a collision ( repetition of some numbers), but I want to make sure they all the numbers from 0 to 100 have been generated, and probably the total of number generated will be more than 100 because of the collision.

Comment: That's what this code does. Both versions produce the same answer as the version from echorange (apart from his off by one error). Incidentally, any code like this needs to be properly tested. This can be a little tricky when you are dealing with random numbers. A useful tool can be to use random.seed to repeatedly test with the same sequence of random numbers. That's what I did to check my code gave the same answer.